# Can Enterprise Guide delete local files?

Tags: sas, enterprise-guide

I know that recent versions of EG can copy files between a SAS server and the local Windows filesystem. But is there any way of getting EG to delete a file as a step in a process flow?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you're running EG connected to a server that does not have access to your local PC, I don't believe you can without using .NET or something inside EG.  You cannot do something like run an X command or similar, because SAS is not on your local machine and can't access it.

It should be possible however to script (using .NET) an extension to EG to do something like this, though (the same way the copy files extension was originally written).  But it wouldn't be a SAS process.

Note: The original task was described in a [blog post by Chris Hemedinger](http://blogs.sas.com/content/sasdummy/2012/12/06/copy-files-in-sas-eg/); that post did not however describe how to actually write such an extension beyond detailing that it uses SAS Workspace APIs.  You might look into that first.